# Python file transfer (tcp socket), problem with slow network

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, proxy, file-transfer

I setted up a secure socket using Tor and socks, but i'm facing a problem when sending large amount of data

**Sender:**

```
socket.send(message.encode())
```

**Receiver:**

```
chunks = []

while 1:
    part = connection.recv(4096)
    chunks.append(part.decode())

    if len(part) < 4096:
        break

response = "".join(chunks)
```

Since the network speed is not consistent in a loop i don't always fill the 4096b buffer, so the loop breaks and i don't receive the full data.

Lowering the buffer size doesn't seem an option because the "packet" size can be as low as 20b sometimes

Answer (score 0):

TCP can split your package data in any amount of pieces it wants. So you should **never** rely on other end of a socket on the size of the packet received. You have to invent another mechanism for detecting end of message/end of file.

If you are going to send only one blob and close socket, then on server side you just read until you get False value:

```
while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    if data:
        print(data)
        # continue 
    else:
        sock.close()
        break
```

If you are going to send multiple messages, you have to decide, what will be the separator between them. For text protocols it is a good idea to use lineending. You can then enjoy the power of Twisted `LineReceiver` protocol and others.

If you are doing a binary protocol, it's a common practice to preface your each message with size byte/word/dword.

Answer (score 0):

Try using structure to pass the length of the incoming data first to the receiver, "import struct". That way the receiving end knows exactly how much data to receive. In this example bytes are being sent over the socket, the examples here I've borrowed from my github upload github.com/nsk89/netcrypt for reference and cut out the encryption steps from the send function as well as it sending a serialised dictionary.

*Edit* I should also clarify that when you send data over the socket especially if your sending multiple messages they all sit in the stream as one long message. Not every message is 4096 bytes in length. If one is 2048 in length and the next 4096 and you receive 4096 on your buffers you'll receive the first message plus half of the next message or completely hang waiting for more data that doesn't exist.

```
data_to_send = struct.pack('>I', len(data_to_send)) + data_to_send # pack the length of data in the first four bytes of data stream, >I indicates internet byte order

    socket_object.sendall(data_to_send)  # transport data



def recv_message(socket_object):
    raw_msg_length = recv_all(socket_object, 4)  # receive first 4 bytes of data in stream
    if not raw_msg_length:
        return None

    # unpack first 4 bytes using network byte order to retrieve incoming message length
    msg_length = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msg_length)[0]

    return recv_all(socket_object, msg_length)  # recv rest of stream up to message length

def recv_all(socket_object, num_bytes):
    data = b''
    while len(data) < num_bytes:  # while amount of data recv is less than message length passed
        packet = socket_object.recv(num_bytes - len(data))  # recv remaining bytes/message
        if not packet:
            return None
        data += packet
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, no need to decode the every part before combine them to a chunk, combine all the parts to a chunk and then decode the chunk.

For your situation, the better way is using 2 steps.

Step1: sender send the size of the message, receiver take this size and ready to receive the message.

Step2: sender send the message, receiver combine the data if necessary.

**Sender**

```
# Step 1
socket.send( str(len(message.encode())).encode() ) 
# Step 2
socket.send(message.encode("utf-8"))
```

**Receiver**

```
# Step 1
message_size = connection.recv(1024) 
print("Will receive message size：",message_size.decode())

# Step 2
recevied_size  = 0 
recevied_data = b''
  while recevied_size < int(message_size.decode()):
      part = connection.recv(1024)
      recevied_size += len(part)
      recevied_data += part
  else:
      print(recevied_data.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
      print("message receive done ....",recevied_size)
```